# Bluetooth - can I use additional Bluetooth adapter on MBP

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

I currently have 2 MBPs (Intel and M1). I have a magic keyboard, magic trackpad, and a Logitech Bluetooth mouse.

I'd like to use my AirPods for audio, but it seems that while the output works fine, the voice is "robotic". I think it might be because of Bluetooth (since I already have a lot of devices connected). Could that be the issue?

In the case that it actually is the issue, I wonder if I can add a Bluetooth USB adapter on my docking station (Dell D6000) to connect my keyboard and trackpad to it (and configure both MBP to use that adapter for them), and use built-in controller for mouse & AirPods / future Bluetooth headset.

Comment: "Robotic voice" - is this the built-in notification voice from the device itself? TBH/ if voices in general (podcasts, phone calls) sound robotic, the quality of the music will be affected as well. As for whether the BT adapter from the Dell will work or not, just try it out! You can't break anything.

Comment: "Robotic", in zoom/teams meetings for instance, they cannot hear me well. Dell dock doesn't have built in bluetooth adapter, i was thinking of adding usb adapter specifically for keyboard/trackpad to reduce load on the built-in one, since they will always stay near the dock. I don't know how to configure that as well in MacOS settings, like map BT device to specific dapter

Comment: You can, but be careful. There's a bug in MBPs (at least the last gen Intel ones) where you can brick the internal Bluetooth by plugging in external USB bluetooth adapters. I did it by accident switching a USB hub from my desktop to my Macbook. eg. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253036820

Comment: Also, pretty sure you can use a USB adapter, but you can't configure different devices to use different adapters.